# Proof of Local Boundedness

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that  $\ f(x)=x^2$ is locally bounded at $x=2$. I am using the definition of local boundedness that states that a function $\ f$ is locally bounded if at $\ x=c$ there is a $\delta>0$ and some $M>0$ such that $\ |f(x)|<M$ whenever $\ x$ $ \epsilon$ $ (c-\delta, c+\delta) $.

Comment: restrict to some close interval inside $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, and use properties of continuous function on closed and bounded set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f(x)| = |(x - 2 + 2)^2| = |(x - 2)^2 + 4(x - 2) + 4| \leq |x - 2|^2 + 4\cdot |x - 2| + 4$ < $\delta^2 + 4\cdot \delta + 4 = (\delta + 2)^2$. If we want $\delta < 0.01$, then we can take $M = (0.01 + 2)^2 = 2.01^2 = 4.0401$, and in general we can take $M = (\delta + 2)^2$

Answer (score 0):

A $\delta-\epsilon$  argument should do it. Consider $f(x)$, then , select an $\epsilon$ and a $\delta$ so that $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon $$ when $0<|x-x_0|< \delta$. Then $M:=f(x)+\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $f(x)$ in $(x-\delta, x+ \delta)$